# How to properly autoresize splitPanels and their elements

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

My form consists of one splitContainer with two horitzontal panels, several buttons on the top panel and charts on the bottom panel.

When the form loads, the top panel is cut and some of the elements are hidden/cut. Moreover if I resize the form, none of the elements or splitContainer resize.

How can properly do it?

I tried with the autoresize property in `Form_Load()`

```
//this.AutoSize = true;
//this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

These are the splitContainer properties

```
//
// splitContainer1
// 
this.splitContainer1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.splitContainer1.FixedPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel1;
this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
this.splitContainer1.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal;
// 
// splitContainer1.Panel1
// 
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.btnPlay);
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.grpOptions);
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.grpDisplay);
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.splitContainer1_Panel1_Paint);
// 
// splitContainer1.Panel2
// 
this.splitContainer1.Panel2.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 561);
this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 69;
this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
```

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `the top panel is cut and some of the elements are hidden/cut` that is because you set FixedPanel in splitContainer : `this.splitContainer1.FixedPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel1;` remove this line

Comment: I removed but I still have the same behavior.

Comment: does `Panel1` resize? if problem with `none of the elements or splitContainer resize` remains , include designer code for them. screenshot also would be nice

Comment: I noticed I can resize Panel1 by dragging the cursor when the form is load. I don't want that. Added screenshot of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you anchor the controls on the splitcontainer

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend putting in a `TableLayoutPanel` on the top panel and put buttons in the cells. You can then set resize behaviour of rows and columns in `TableLayoutPanel` either percentage or absolute value. Ensure that `Dock` property for buttons is set to `Fill`. This is will ensure smooth and proper resizing of controls. You can go for similar approach for bottom panel as well.

Comment: I changed the form to: SplitContainer with a top pannel and bottom pannel and then, inside each pannel a TableLayoutPanel. However, the top pannel is stil cut (same as screenshot). How can I fix it?